# Asymptotically free/flat

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, conformal-field-theory, yang-mills

> What does the expression: *"...the theory becomes asymptotically free/conformal"* mean?

If it means that the spacetime $M$ on which the fields are defined is e invariant under conformal transformations; then free would mean that the fields are invariant under "shifts" in the underlying space?

If it means that the correlation functions $\left< \phi_i(x) \phi_j(x)\right>$ are invariant under the above groups, does this imply that spacetime has the symmetries as well?

Comment: "Asymptotically free/conformal" here might mean what is sometimes called "asymptotically safe". This means that the theory is UV-complete and has a UV fixed point which is a conformal, possibly free, theory. Conformality of course refers to the theory and not to the manifold on which it is placed.

Answer (score 0):

Asymptotically free implies that the beta function for the coupling constant of the theory goes to zero, and $\beta(g) = 0$ would make a theory conformal, as the coupling constant would be independent of the energy scale of the theory.
It is easy to check whether the beta function is zero classically or not. It is the quantum corrections which make life difficult, and for a theory to be exactly conformal, the beta function must be zero to all loop orders. 
For example $\phi ^4$ in 4 dimensions is marginally irrelevant.
QCD in 4d is asymptotically free, as it's beta function is negative, and hence it is almost zero at very high energy scales.